# Exception handling of non numerical value

Tags: java, exception

Hi how to and where do I add the exception handling to inputs that are non numerical? I am unsure as to how I am supposed to write the code to handle the exception. I would like an error message to appear when non numerical data is input by the user. THanks in advance for your help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RotaryLunch {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
    final int padult = 20;
    final int pkids = 12;
    final int psalad = 4;
    final int pdessert = 5; 
    double quantity,order,reorder,price = 0,total = 0;      
    int loop=0;

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome! What would you like to order? ");
    System.out.println("01 Adult Lunch Set $20");
    System.out.println("02 Kids Lunch Set $12");
    System.out.println("03 Salad Side $4");
    System.out.println("04 Dessert $5");

    do {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.print("Enter Code Order > ");
        order=keyboard.nextDouble();
        if (order==01) {
            System.out.println("Order Description : Adult Lunch Set $20");
            price = padult;
        }
        else if (order==02) {
            System.out.println("Order Description : Kids Lunch Set $12");
            price = pkids;
        }
        else if (order==03) {
            System.out.println("Order Description : Salad Side $4");
            price=psalad;
        }
        else if (order==04) {
            System.out.println("Order Description : Dessert $5");
            price=pdessert;
        }
            System.out.print("Enter quantity > ");
            quantity=keyboard.nextDouble();
            total+=price*quantity;
            System.out.print("Press 1 if you would like to order more and press 2 if you're done > ");
            reorder=keyboard.nextDouble();
            if (reorder==1) {
                loop++;
            }
            else {loop=0;            
            } 
        }while (loop>=1);  

    keyboard.close();       
    System.out.println("Your total is $"+total);
    }
```

}

Comment: read up on "try catch" blocks. Also understand that your preferred IDE is not relevant

Comment: Think about where such an `Exception` might be thrown... Where are you reading the input? What method could *complain* about an input mismatch?